# What kind of SSL certificate do I need for Exchange 2013?

Tags: ssl, exchange, exchange-2013

We're running a single domain on a single Exchange 2013 server. I'm currently trying to determine what kind of SSL cert I need.

Right now I'm unsure why I need a UC (Unified Communications) Certificate like [**this**](http://ssl.comodo.com/unified-communications-uc-ssl-certificates.php?key5sk1=c08e528e87fe17ea9827bbb8b27f7cb4d467994e&key5sk2=2128&key5sk3=1375737134000&key5sk8=&key5sk9=1375735066000&key5sk10=2128&key5sk11=1375737136000&key5sk12=&key5sk13=1375737141000&key5sk14=1907&key5sk15=1375737148000&key6sk1=&key6sk2=CH280150095&key6sk3=7&key6sk4=en-us&key6sk5=US&key6sk6=1&key6sk7=Google&key6sk8=118800&key6sk9=12801024&key6sk10=true&key6sk11=670ce2df6dcf6c4c93db0dcf74e77755d29cff40&key6sk12=2034&key7sk1=2&key7sk2=43&key7sk3=196106&key1sk1=ors&key1sk2=Google) one.

I can understand why something like [**this**](https://comodosslstore.com/essentialssl-wildcard.aspx) wildcard certificate would be necessary.

Any direction would be helpful!

Comment: It is considered best practice to use SAN over Wildcard for security reasons. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351044%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx Microsoft also keeps a list of CA that offer UC certs. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929395

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UC certificate is perfectly fine. The only names you really need are the external URL you will use for OWA/Outlook Anywhere (such as mail.mycompany.com) and autodiscover.mycompany.com. If you plan on using TLS for encrypted mail transport, you will need to include the FQDN that you use on your send connector, which also could just be mail.mycompany.com.

I would recommend a wildcard certificate if you want to use one certificate for a ton of other web applications under the same domain name. You will have to set your Outlook Provider appropriately if you use a wildcard cert:

```
Set-OutlookProvider EXPR -CertPrincipalName 'msstd:*.mycompany.com'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Right now I'm leaning towards the wildcard cert, mostly based on it costing approx 1/3 the price, are there any real technical reasons why I should go with the UC cert over the WildCard?

Comment: Not sure about this in 2013, but 2010 and wildcard cert was a major pain, Outlook Anywhere didn't like wildcard certs, I had to buy a SAN cert for it to actually work, this didn't work with me: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc535023(EXCHG.80).aspx

Comment: Hi Noor, the issue with Outlook Anywhere is addressed by the PowerShell one-liner I provided. Ernie- I'm finding out that transport TLS won't work with a wildcard certificate. If you don't mind my asking, what provider are you using that has wildcards for 1/3 the price of a UC cert?

Comment: @JeremyLyons My numbers might be slightly skewed as I'm looking at wholesale, but the links in my post are for Comodo certs where the retail "Essential WildCard" (Second Link) is listed at retail $98usd for 1 year and the UC cert (First Link) starts at retail $235usd.

Comment: So you're saying the Wildcard will work fine by using the PS command you posted there?

Comment: Yes - I configure servers to use them routinely.